# Get amount of matched rows and total rows in a join

Tags: r, data.table

I want to see how many matches result from an inner join as a count as well as a percentage. I can do the following:

```r
library(data.table)
a <- data.table(id = 1:10, key = "id")
b <- data.table(id = 8:14, key = "id")

### Option 1
a[b, .(matched_count = .N, matched_percent = .N / a[, .N]), nomatch = NULL]
```

or

```r
### Option 2
a[, total := .N][
  b, .(matched_count = .N, matched_percent = .N / unique(total)), nomatch = NULL]
```

both yielding the desired result:

```r
#    matched_count matched_percent
# 1:             3             0.3
```

I don't like option 2 because I create a new column in `a`. I don't like option 1 because I have to reference `a` twice (if I change the name of `a` I have to change it twice here, this feels like error prone).

Do I have an option to get the original number of rows in a join?